# table view edit mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have a Navigation controller on which a table view is there. I wanted two button on that navigation bar i.e. "Add to Favourite" and the other is "Edit".

Both the button should fire the event that makes the table view go in editing mode. From the "Add to favorite button i want the table view to go in insertion mode i.e. a +green sign in front of every cell and with the Edit button i want it to go in deletion mode i.e. - negative sign in front of every cell.

I have sorted out the Edit button , but i am not able to do the Add to favorite button.
Sticking my code here for reference

The viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add to Favourite" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveAction:)]autorelease];




    [super viewDidLoad];




- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];

    //Do not let the user add if the app is in edit mode.
    if(editing)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    else
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;


    NSLog(@"i came till here");   }
```

In this method i am just retrieving values from database and deleting it from the DB as well as the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [appdelegate.tablearr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"id"];

      //  [tableView beginUpdates];

        sqlite3 *db;
        int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
        dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
        if (dbrc) {
            NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
            return;
        }

        sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database

        NSString *deleteStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"Hell\" WHERE id='%@'", keyValue];
        const char *deleteStatement = [deleteStatementsNS UTF8String];
        dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);
        dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps);
        sqlite3_finalize(dbps);
        sqlite3_close(db);


        [appdelegate.tablearr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        //Delete the object from the table.
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

And this is the one method thats get fired when i press the add to favorite button

```
-(void)saveAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

    NSLog(@"here");



 }
```

Now what should i write in this method so that the table view goes into the editing and with an + green insertion thing in front of every cell ??

Answer (score 1):

To put the table into editing mode, you need to use:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

To switch between insertion and deletion modes, you need to implement `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`.  I.e.:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (some condition)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```